# SvelteKit Endpoint Always returning 200 status

Tags: svelte, endpoint, sveltekit

I am using SvelteKit and am having an issue with endpoints. I am posting to an endpoint and it's always returning a 200 status, even with a hardcoded 400 status.

Login.svelte

```js
const res = await fetch('login', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        redirect: `${window.location.origin}/app/dashboard`
    })
});
```

ENDPOINT - login.js

```js
export const post = async ({request}) => {

  console.log("Inside request");
  
  return {
    status: 400
  };
}
```

The endpoint is being hit as seen through a console log, but the status is returned 200 in a Response object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is subtle. But it makes sense in the end.

If we read the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints-page-endpoints) carefully, we can figure out what's going on. Specifically:

> Because the page and route have the same URL, you will need to include an accept: application/json header to get JSON from the endpoint rather than HTML from the page.

Because you are using page endpoints, (rather than standalone endpoints) Sveltekit has 2 routes for `POST /login`. One that returns the HTML page (the `login.svelte`), and one that returns the JSON (the page endpoint defined in `login.js`).

So what we need to do is tell the server that we are expecting the result in `application/json` rather than `text/*` (the latter is the default for fetch it seems). This way the server knows which route to return.

There are 2 solutions to this: 1. Update your fetch statement to include the `accept` header; or 2: Rename your login.js to something that isn't also a route, so the server doesn't get confused what to return.

I personally prefer the first one as it's technically more correct. So then your `login.svelte` function would become:

```js
const res = await fetch('/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'accept': 'application/json' }, //Added the header here
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email,
    redirect: `${window.location.origin}/app/dashboard`
  })
})
```